# zip error: Nothing to do!

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Не получается переписать прогу с учебника  "A Byte of Python" без ошибки.

```
import os
import time

source = ['C:\\Users\Evgeniy\Документы']
target_dir = 'D:\\Евгений'  # Подставьте тот путь, который вы будете 
использовать.
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'
zip_command = 'zip -qr {0} {1}'.format(target, ' '.join(source))

print(zip_command)
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

Пишет:

```
zip -qr D:\Евгений\20190921112503.zip C:\Users\Евгений\Документы

zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -qr 
D:\�������\20190921112503.zip . -i 
C:\Users\�������\���������)
Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ
```

Zip команду скачал и добавил в PATH. Может не правильно скачал или не так добавил в PATH. В командной строке пишет:

```
C:\Users\Евгений>zip /?

zip error: Nothing to do! (/?.zip)

C:\Users\Евгений>.zip /?
".zip" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

C:\Users\Евгений>zip_command /?
"zip_command" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

C:\Users\Евгений>zip_command
"zip_command" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Система у меня Windows 10 pro. Python 3.7.4.
Помогите разобраться, плиз. Никак не получается. Что я не так делаю?

Comment: Евгений, попробуй использовать путь без кириллицы.

Comment: Всё тоже самое.

Comment: Спасибо. Я вроде бы справился. Вроде бы как то так.

Comment: В примере кода `zip_command` - это имя переменной Python, оно не должно никак работать в командной строке. `.zip` - это просто расширение файла архива, которое добавляется к имени файла. Тоже отдельно от имени файла не имеет смысла. Просто `zip` в командной строке у вас запускается, но вы не передали в него никаких осмысленных параметров, вот он и пишет, "nothing to do".

Comment: Благодарю. Понял.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо выбрать путь без кириллицы, сам столкнулся с данной проблемой

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо. С этим вопросом разобрался. Код такой:

```
import os
import time

source = ['C:\\Users']
target_dir = "D:\\Программы"  # Подставьте тот путь, который вы будете 
использовать.
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'
zip_command = 'zip -qr {0} {1}'.format(target, ' '.join(source))

print(zip_command)
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

Вывод:

```
zip -qr D:\Программы\20190921120404.zip C:\Users


Резервная копия успешно создана в D:\Программы\20190921120404.zip
```

Но почему то в командной строке команда zip всё равно выдаёт ошибку, только не знаю почему, может подскажите?

```
C:\Users\Евгений>.zip /?
".zip" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

C:\Users\Евгений>zip /?

zip error: Nothing to do! (/?.zip)
```

А в самой программе можно просто писать один диск, например: D:\. И тогда резервная копия создаётся. В общем я такое решение нашёл, если не правильно - подскажите.

Answer (score 0):

Я для русских папок стал использовать конвертор юникода:
Например: D:\Программы 
конвертировал в: \u0044\u003a\u005c\u005c\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0433\u0440\u0430\u043c\u043c\u044b

Answer (score 0):

У меня такая же проблема возникла.
Оказалось, что для некоторых действий с файлами/папками из документов необходимы права администратора. Решается добавлением опции "!" в команду:
`zip -qr! D:\Программы\20190921120404.zip C:\Users`