# Ошибка в коде резервного копирования из книги A Byte of Python

Tags: python

```
import os
import zipfile
import time

# 1. Файлы и каталоги, которые необходимо скопировать, собираются в список.
source = ['C:\\Users\\Admin\\PycharmProjects', 'C:\\Code']
# Заметьте, что для имён, содержащих пробелы, необходимо использовать
# двойные кавычки внутри строки.

# 2. Резервные копии должны храниться в основном каталоге резерва.
target_dir = 'D:\\Backup' # Подставьте тот путь, который вы будете использовать.

# 3. Файлы помещаются в zip-архив.
# 4. Именем для zip-архива служит текущая дата и время.
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

# 5. Используем команду "zip" для помещения файлов в zip-архив
zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

# Запускаем создание резервной копии
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

Переписал сначала из книги, выдавало ошибку. Попробовал с import zipfile, все равно не работает и строка серого цвета(объясните кто знает почему). 
Результат программы:

D:\Python3.8\python.exe C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/Exercises/backup_ver1.py
Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ
"zip" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1053054/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-a-byte-of-python-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5

Comment: Не пробовали поиском по сайту воспользоваться? Дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/998585

Comment: @andreymal Формально не дубликат — ответов там нет.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica формально да, фактически в комментариях ответили ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [zip error: Nothing to do!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1026541/zip-error-nothing-to-do)

Answer (score 1):

Настойте терминал, в котором запускаете программу, чтобы он понимал кириллицу.
Тогда вместо `<?>` увидите ошибку:

> "zip" не является внутренней или внешней
> командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Просто выполните перед запуском:

```
set "PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin;%PATH%"
```