# "zip" Hе является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом

Tags: python

Ошибка связана с неуказанным путём в PATH для задачи из книги A Byte of Python. Но после указания пути, ошибка возникает снова. 
Программа:

```
`import os
import time

# 1. Файлы и каталоги, которые необходимо скопировать, собираются в список.
source = ['"C:\\Новая папка\\img296.jpg"']
# Заметьте, что для имён, содержащих пробелы, необходимо использовать
# двойные кавычки внутри строки.

target_dir = 'D:\\Backup'

# Создаем архив
# Имя архива - текущее дата и время
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ''.join(source))

print(zip_command)

if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
     print('Копирование выполнено успешно в', target)
else:
     print('Копирование не удалось!')`
```

PATH:  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Запустите cmd и введите zip

Comment: Выдаёт то же, что и в названии вопроса

Comment: Значит для zip не прописан путь. Обратите внимание что переменных path две. Проверьте что zip.exe есть по указанному пути.

Comment: Прописал в обеих. Всё также

Comment: для работы с архивами лучше использовать библиотеку [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html)
Пример кода: `import zipfile with zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zip_file, 'r') as zip_ref: zip_ref.extractall(directory_to_extract_to)`

Comment: Вы уже задавали этот вопрос вчера, и я там даже отвечал: [Ошибка в коде резервного копирования из книги A Byte of Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1070746/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-a-byte-of-python)

Comment: Выполните перезагрузку